# Matrix of objects class

Tags: c#, class, object, matrix, constructor

I have written 3 classes: KompresorSilnik, KompresorObiekt and Mrowka.

I want to create a matrix of objects of class KompresorObiekt ( it's a GrafObiektow method ). In the constructor of KompresorObiekt, I create 4 instances of KompresorSilnik. I have a method, zwrocListe() which returns a list of int[] from 0000 to 2222.

The question is: was that correct or not implementation?

```
public class KompresorSilnik
{
    public double minFlow;
    public double maxFlow;
    public bool typ;
    public int stan;

    public KompresorSilnik()
    {
    }

    public KompresorSilnik(double minFlow, double maxFlow, bool typ, int stan)
    {
        this.minFlow = minFlow;
        this.maxFlow = maxFlow;
        this.typ = typ;
        this.stan = stan;
     }
}
```

This is my second class KompresorObiekt

```
public class KompresorObiekt
{
    public KompresorObiekt() { }

    public KompresorObiekt( List<int[]> list, int x, int y)
    {
        double k1Max = 3000000.0;
        double k1Min = 10000.0;
        double k2Max = 200000.0;
        double k2Min = 5000.0;
        double K3Max = 100000000.0;
        double k3Min = 800.0;
        double k4Max = 10000.0;
        double k4Min = 2000.0;
        KompresorSilnik komp1 = new KompresorSilnik(k1Min, k1Max, false, list[x][y]);
        KompresorSilnik komp2 = new KompresorSilnik(k2Min, k2Max, true, list[x][y+1]);
        KompresorSilnik komp3 = new KompresorSilnik(k3Min, K3Max, false, list[x][y+2]);
        KompresorSilnik komp4 = new KompresorSilnik(k4Min, k4Max, true, list[x][y+3]);
    }
}
```

and the last one Mrowka

```
public class Mrowka
{
    List<int[]> zwrocListe()
    {
        List<int[]> arrList = new List<int[]>();
        int[] ArrayOfInts = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                    {
                        ArrayOfInts[0] = i;
                        ArrayOfInts[1] = j;
                        ArrayOfInts[2] = k;
                        ArrayOfInts[3] = m;

                        int[] arc = (int[])ArrayOfInts.Clone();
                        arrList.Add(arc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return arrList;
    }

    KompresorObiekt[][] GrafObiektow(int time)
    {
        KompresorObiekt[][] graf = new KompresorObiekt[time][];
        int numNodes = zwrocListe().Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < graf.Length; ++i)
            graf[i] = new KompresorObiekt[numNodes];

        for (int i = 0; i < time; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < numNodes; ++j)
            {
                graf[i][j] = new KompresorObiekt(zwrocListe(), j, 0);

            }
        return graf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "The question is: was that correct or not implementation?". Is there an actual problem here? If so, what is the error message, and where does it happen?

Comment: I'm not sure that the method GrafObiektow saves objects.

Comment: Oh, and why in KompresorObiekt.GrafObiektow() don't you cache the object returned by zwrocListe() ? Seems a bit wasteful. In fact, since it doesn't refer to any state or parameters, why don't you make this a static object created by the static constructor?

Comment: The best thing for you to do would be to add more detail to your question. And run through your code in the debugger.

Comment: Define "saves objects": Returns them via a parameter? Stores them in object state? Stores them in global state?

Comment: graf[i][j] = new KompresorObiekt(zwrocListe(), j, 0); <- I create a matrix of objects ( i think, but im not sure:P) then i would like to use a parameter of objects ( from KompresorSilnik like typ, stan minFlow and maxFlow to calculate)